# Numpy minimum for a given column

Tags: python, numpy

I have a two-dimensional numpy array of data, holding symmetric information about pairs of elements I'm tracking, very much like a round-robin bracket in a tournament. Keeping with that analogy, each player occupies one row with the column data being their score against a given opponent. For "legacy" reasons, all scores will be positive numbers except for the score against oneself, which will be 0.

Let's say I want to find the worst score of a given player, returning both the score and the opponent they played for that score. How might I do this?

The mediocre version might look like:

```
minimum = float('inf')
min_opp = None
for opponent_id in player_ids:
    if opponent_id != player_id:
        score = match_matrix[player_id, opponent_id]
        if score < minimum:
            minimum = score
            min_opp = opponent_id
return minimum, min_opp
```

But that's not using the power of numpy at all. I feel like there should be an easy solution, but I cannot seem to find it.

```
score = np.min(match_matrix[player, :])
```

gives the self-score, and I can't quite make the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799060/how-to-find-the-minimum-value-from-a-part-of-a-column-in-numpy-array) work correctly.

Thanks!

EDIT: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394377/minimum-of-numpy-array-ignoring-diagonal) provides good ideas, but only gets the minimum of the entire array, not a single row.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29394823/6614295) answer your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minimum of Numpy Array Ignoring Diagonal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394377/minimum-of-numpy-array-ignoring-diagonal)

Comment: @jotasi. That answers the question for an entire matrix, not for a row-by-row case. I wouldn't consider it a dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the given row, mask out the self-score and return the minimum of the remainder. Basically what you did but with an extra masking step. I would also recommend using [`np.argmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) instead of `np.min` because it returns the index of the minimum, which is much more informative in this case:

```
mask = np.ones(match_matrix.shape(1), dtype=np.bool)
mask[player] = False
opponent = np.argmin(match_matrix[player, mask])
if opponent >= player:
    opponent += 1
score = match_matrix[player, opponent]
```

Comment: Okay! That's readable and does what I need it to. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.  `np.min()` will give you the minimum value in a row, and `np.where` can tell you where that value is.

```
grid = np.random.randint(0,10,[5,5]) #Random matchups of 5x5 players
player = 1
low_score = np.min(grid[player][grid[player]>0])    #Only look at positive scores
opponent = np.where(grid[player]==low_score)[0]
```

Here, opponents will be an array of opponents, in case `player` got the same low score against multiple opponents.

Comment: `argmin` + indexing is probably more efficient than `min` + `where`.